# Java how to remove listener

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I have problem with my Listener, I don't know how permanently remove listener for my nameFieldLoginStage. Now when user switch few times Login/Register button, my method is called many times and my server get many identical String send by Client class. I want to remove listener when my method would be ended.

```
 @FXML
public TextField nameFieldLoginStage;


private void checkUsernameRegister() {

        nameFieldLoginStage.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            imageUsernameLoginStage.setVisible(true);
            if(registerButtonLoginStage.isSelected()) {
                if (getPropertyUsername().length() >= 3 && getPropertyUsername().length() < 13) {
                    client.checkUserName(getPropertyUsername());

                    do {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } while (!client.propertyCheckingFlagProperty().get());

                    if (client.getUsernameFlag()) {
                        imageUsernameLoginStage.setImage(new Image(ICONS_CANCEL_PNG));
                        usernameFlag = false;
                    } else {
                        imageUsernameLoginStage.setImage(new Image(ICONS_ACCEPT_PNG));
                        usernameFlag = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    imageUsernameLoginStage.setImage(new Image(ICONS_LENGTH_PNG));
                    usernameFlag = false;
                }


                setAcceptButtonLoginStage();
            }else
                imageUsernameLoginStage.setImage(null);
        });

    }
```

Comment: well, what is `nameFieldLoginStage` and what type is  `nameFieldLoginStage.textProperty()`...

Comment: @FXML
    public TextField nameFieldLoginStage;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you will have to create an instance of the listener. This instance you add as a listener to the textProperty and from inside the listener, you can remove yourself. Usually I create an instance for this instead of using a lambda:

```
ChangeListener<String> changeListener = new ChangeListener<>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        ...
        nameFieldLoginStage.textProperty().removeListener(this);
    }
};
nameFieldLoginStage.textProperty().addListener(changeListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to remove an annonymous listener, how about using an inner class that implements a listener? so you can properly initialize a listener object. This way you can make use of the removeListener() function.

Or it sounds like you want to executes once, maybe using a task and a scheduler instead?

Comment: Anonymus classes are unproblematic, since you can use `this` to refer to the instance. Lambda expressions (like the one used in the question) are different though, since `this` refers to the surrounding type instead. Still a listener could be referenced, if it's e.g. stored in a field... A scheduler probably won't do the trick, since a listener could be triggered multiple times...